# report the names of all sellers who did not make any sales in 2020

Tags: mysql, sql, join, anti-join

Customer table:

| customer_id | customer_name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Alice |
| 102 | Bob |
| 103 | Charlie |

Orders table:

| order_id | sale_date | order_cost | customer_id | seller_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | 1500 | 101 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-05-25 | 2400 | 102 | 2 |
| 3 | 2019-05-25 | 800 | 101 | 3 |
| 4 | 2020-09-13 | 1000 | 103 | 2 |
| 5 | 2019-02-11 | 700 | 101 | 2 |

Seller table:

| seller_id | seller_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Daniel |
| 2 | Elizabeth |
| 3 | Frank |

> Write an SQL query to report the names of all sellers who did not make any sales in 2020

This question was asked to me in a data analyst interview and I provided the query below. But my query is partially incorrect because it also gives those sellers who made sales in another year along with 2020 like Elizabeth because she made sales in 2019 and 2020. So I want a query in SQL which only gives the name of all sellers who made sales in 2020 only.

```
select s.seller_name
from seller_table s
JOIN order_table o
ON s.seller_id = o.seller_id
where year(sale_date) <> 2020;
```

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If asking reflect research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

switch to a not in or not exists.

```
  select seller_name from seller where id not in 
    (select seller_id from order_table where year(sale_date) = 2020)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query selects all sellers that have an order in a year that is not 2020. This is not what you want.

You want to select sellers for which **not exists** an order in year 2020.

```
select s.seller_name
from seller_table s
where not exists
(
  select null
  from order_table o
  where o.seller_id = s.seller_id
  and year(o.sale_date) = 2020
);
```

There are other ways to achieve the same, but this is the most straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Two equivalent approaches:

```
select s.seller_name
from seller_table s
where not exists (select 1 from order_table where o.seller_id=s.seller_id and year(sale_date)=2020)
```

and

```
select s.seller_name
from seller_table s
left join order_table o on o.seller_id=s.seller_id and year(o.sale_date)=2020
where o.seller_id is null
```

The former expresses the intent of the query better; the latter better represents how the query will actually be executed.